# Looking for Alexander Ormond on 1861 census?

Tags: 19th-century, census-records, scotland, 1860s

Looking for Alexander Ormond born in 1841 in Forfar on the 1861 census. I can't seem to find him or any of his immediate family for that matter.

His mother's name was Jane/Jean Ormond (nee Peter).

His siblings were William, James, Mary, David and Elizabeth and his father Charles was dead as of 1861, dying in 1857.

I do know he worked on ships at some point so this may be why he isn't present but I would still expect to find his mother or siblings somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the family of Jean Osment, with James, Alexander (19), Elizabeth and John?

Anytime a whole family disappears, I look for common mistakes in the spelling of the last name.

Parish: Forfar; ED: 11; Page: 3; Line: 14; Roll: CSSCT1861_42
Source Information Ancestry.com. 1861 Scotland Census [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations Inc, 2006.

Comment: hi Jane, thanks for this, much appreciated. Can this be found anywhere except Ancestry? I can't find it on Scotland's People or Findmypast

Comment: Sorry, I can't find them on Findmypast either, even when just searching for their address, 25 Glamis Rd.  Ancestry doesn't have images, so I can't see who else is on the same page, or how else the name might have been transcribed. Jean age 44 was a jute weaver; James, age 25 a Quarrier; Alexander 19, agricultural labourer; Elizabeth, age 11, Linen Winder; and John age 9 scholar.

Comment: Jean Orment on familysearch and on find my past.

Comment: interesting to know there was another child John.

Comment: If you want to see the original image then [ScotlandsPeople](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/) is the place to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try widening your search terms. For example, there's a 19 year old A Ormond in the High Church registration district in Lanarkshire:

[image: A Ormond]

Also, try extending your search to the rest of the UK.

Comment: It's not the same A Ormond as that one was born in Lanarkshire, and the one I'm looking for was born in Forfar, Forfarshire/Angus

Comment: I found a Post Office directory in 1961-62 for Alexander Ormond in Dundee that may be the same one, listed as a weaver but no census record